# Wordpress images seems to upload but they are not

Tags: php, wordpress, image

We have a wordpress site used for development and testing purposes.
On that site we use the woocommerce plugin to build up the e-shop. Until yesterday the uploading of images was working fine.
Today we have a problem that the images uploaded to media library show that they are uploaded but in reality they are not. The thumbnail is blank and the file is not uploaded on the wp-content folder as examined via ftp.
The core installation is updated to the latest version.Permissions are on the suggested values 
Any ideas what could cause this issue?
Regards

Comment: This may be due to some plugin conflicts. Try to disable the plugins one by one and check if it works or not

Answer (score 1):

After much research the problem was nailed to hosting issues. Our service provider had hardware issues with the harddrive that after repairing it my problem was also resolved.